# PhoneGap Barcode Scanner plugin crashes after scan - android

Tags: android, cordova

I have created a test app on android using PhoneGap, and this Barcode Scanner plugin:

```
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner
```

My app complies and runs on my phone, and when I click a button to active the plugin it works too. I can scan a barcode but once that happens the app closes.

When debugging I get the following error messages appearing

("example" is the name of my app)

```
netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib spl_proc_plugin.so
netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin:  spl_proc_plugin.so
netstack: STAT_HUB - App org.apache.cordova.example isn't supported
netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib libsocketpoolextend.so
```

So it looks like it is trying to load a library or plugin and is failing. But whenever I google any of those so filenames I don't find anything of use

I am using cordova 2.9.0 and the barcode scanner plugin version is 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue had nothing to do with the scanner plugin. The crash was happenning because of the orientation change. A few config changes (found here --> http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_crashes_on_android_during_orientation_change) helped solve it